# Jmeter load test with 30K users with aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, jmeter, load-testing

My scenario is mentioned below, please provide the solution. 
I need to run 17 HTTP Rest API's for 30K users. 
I will create 6 AWS instances (Slaves) for running 30K (6 Instances*5000 Users) users. 
Each AWS instance (Slave) needs to handle 5K Users. 
I will create 1 AWS instance (Master) for controlling 6 AWS slaves.

1) For Master AWS instance, what instance type and storage I need to use? 
2) For Slave AWS instance, what instance type and storage I need to use? 
3) The main objective is a Single AWS instance need to handle 5000Users (5k) users, for this what instance type and storage I need to use? This objective needs to solve for low cost (pricing)?
Full ELB DNS Name:

Comment: Single AWS instance need to handle 5000Users (5k), for this what instance type and storage I need to use while creating AWS instance? Main objective is, this needs to solve for low cost (pricing)?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is `I don't know`, this is something **you** need to find out how many users you will be able to simulate on this or that AWS instance as it depends on the nature of your test, what it is doing, response size, number of postprocessors/assertions, etc.

So I would recommend the following approach:

1. First of all make sure you are following recommendations from the [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure)
2. Start with single AWS server, i.e. [t2.large](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/) and single virtual user. **Gradually** increase the load at the same time monitor the AWS health (CPU,RAM, Disk, etc) using either [Amazon CloudWatch](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/) or [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/). Once there will be a lack of the monitored metrics (i.e. CPU usage exceeds 90%) stop your test and mention the number of virtual users at this stage (you can use i.e. [Active Threads Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime/) listener for this)
3. Depending on the outcome either switch to other instance type (i.e. `Compute Optimized` if there is a lack of CPU or `Memory Optimized` if there is a lack of RAM) or go for higher spec instance of the same tier (i.e. `t2.xlarge`)
4. Once you get the number of users you can simulate on a single host you should be able to extrapolate it to other hosts.

JMeter master host doesn't need to be as powerful as slave machines, just make sure it has enough memory to handle incoming results.